# Strategy to build big web application system using spring boot

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, vue.js

Im a bit confused of how to build kind of a big web application using spring boot.
Is it ok to use js framework like vue or react or angular to build the UI and buid only rest apis on the spring side ?
Or may be there is a better strategy?
Thank you

Comment: I think your question is not suitable for stackoverflow. Anyway, give us more details like: type (CRM, ERP, CMS, etc), target devices (desktop, mobile),  how many users (concurrent or not), budget restrictions, do you have a complete software team (devs, testers, business analysts, architects, devops, etc) , multi tenant,  windows/microsoft imposition, linux freedom, etc

Comment: And don't forget the children, think of the children.

Comment: @JRichardsz, it's ERP, targerted devices mobile and desktop, I don't understand how are the things related to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to create Client side app as well using Spring Boot as is documented in [official Spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/17/client-side-development-with-spring-boot-applications) I'd still recommend that you separate the concerns and use best suited frameworks for the job:

1. SpringBoot to handle backend API and business logic
2. For the UI best to to use one of the mentioned frameworks that will help you build the Client app more efficiently and just consume the API

Comment: thank you for your answer, so let's say, I decided to use React framework for the client side, now in that case, i would build only the REST APIs and let the whole MVC to be on React side framewrok, is that ok ? or there might be shortcomings in the future?

Comment: MVC (Model, View, Controller) would still be in Backend jurisdiction in a sense - M (Entities and other data structures used in your business logic); V (response DTOs, most often in form of a JSON format that your Client app will consume); C (entry point to your your API). Frontend (React) should fetch the data from your API, present the information and keep track of states of the app in the user journey